# How can I choose multiple rows and send those options to a second UITableView through a prepareForSegue function?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, segue

I'm working in a UITableView which contains 5 rows ("a" to "e"), and when I click on one of the rows, it shows me in the next UITableView the letter I chose as a Header (with the prepareForSegue function). Actually, until this point it works perfectly.. BUT when I try to add more "headers" in the 2nd tableView after clicking in more than one row from the first UITableView, it just show me the last option (for example, if I click first in "a", then "d" and then "c"... the second UITableView just show me the row "c" as a header, not the other 2 rows).

**How can I choose multiple rows and send those options to a second UITableView through a prepareForSegue function?**

My line of codes for the first view are these:

```
let array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

@IBOutlet var initialTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segueA" {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? Content {
            if let selectedRow = initialTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row {
                destination.title = array[selectedRow]
            }
        }

    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.array.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellA", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel!.text = array[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

The second view contains these lines:

```
var contentArray:[String] = []

@IBOutlet var contentTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    contentArray.append(title!)
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return contentArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellContent = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellContent", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cellContent.textLabel!.text = "Second test"
    return cellContent
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return contentArray[section]
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joe.

For solving of you're issue.You should enabled multiple selection by :

`tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES;`

Than you should remember items you selected in first viewContoller. For convenience try to use:

```
var indexPathsForSelectedRows: [NSIndexPath]? { get }
```

And than send this information to the another `viewController` by segue.

Example:

```
let array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

@IBOutlet var initialTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    initialTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = YES
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segueA" {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? Content {
            if let selectedRows = initialTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
                //hear you have option to send items that are selected to another controller or send only indexPath.
            }
        }

    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.array.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellA", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel!.text = array[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. So, when I'm writing `if let selectedRows = initialTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows { destination.title = array[selectedRows] }` ... now gives me an error: "Cannot subscript a value of type [String] with an index of type [NSIndexPath]"

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the selected rows yourself in a list or array

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //check if self._selectedIndices (your array) contains indexPath.row
    //if yes then remove it from array
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None // remove check mark if you want to use it
    //if no then add it to array
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark // add check mark if you want to use it
}
```

then in your prepareForSegue

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // use self._selectedIndices to get the selected row indices
    // self._dataSource[index] for the actual data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just enable multiple selection on the tableview, and use the indexPathsForSelectedRows variant to get the full list. You can then either pass the whole list from your data source + the indexes, or map the indexes to the actual values.